# Are these two definitions of positive measure equivalent?

Tags: measure-theory

Let's consider the two following definitions of a positive measure :

**D1** : Let $\mu$ be an application from a $\sigma$-algebra $T$ to $\overline{\mathbb{R}^+}$.

$\mu$ is called a (positive) measure if and only if :

1)$\mu(\emptyset)=0$

2)for all countable collections $(A_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of pairwise disjoint sets of T , $$\mu(\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}A_n)=\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\mu(A_n)$$

**D2** : Let $\mu$ be an application from a $\sigma$-algebra $T$ to $\overline{\mathbb{R}^+}$.

$\mu$ is called a (positive) measure if and only if :

1. $\mu(\emptyset)=0$

2)$\mu$ is additive , which means for all disjoint pairs $A,B$ of T , $\mu(A\cup B)=\mu(A)+\mu(B)$

3. for all sequence $(A_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of $T$ such that $A_{n+1}\subset{A_n} ,\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\mu(A_0)<\infty$ , we have $$\mu(\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_n)= \lim_{n \to \infty} \mu(A_n)$$
   EDIT:
   I add a 4th condition :
   4)for all sequence $(A_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of $T$ such that $A_{n}\subset A_{n+1} ,\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ , we have $$\mu(\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_n)= \lim_{n \to \infty} \mu(A_n)$$

I think it can show that $(D_1)\implies(D_2)$ , but does $(D_2)\implies (D_1)$ holds ?

Is there a proof by equivalence ?

Comment: They ae not equivalent. Any finitely additive set function $\mu$ satisfying $\mu(\emptyset)=0$ satisfies condition 3) but it need not be countably additive. I think the condition  $\mu(A_0)=0$  should be replaced by  $\mu(A_0)<\infty$.

Comment: Absolutely i typed it wrong , thanks for the feedback , i'm correcting it

Comment: without using the condition that $\mu\left(\bigcup_{k\in \mathbb{N}}A_k\right)<\infty $ it is not so clear that $D_2$ implies $D_1$ except if we can show that if $\mu\left(\bigcup_{k>n}A_k\right)=\infty $ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ necessarily implies that $\sum_{k\geqslant 0}\mu(A_k)=\infty $ also using the axioms of $D_2$ (for a disjoint sequence $\{A_n\}_{n\in \mathbb N}$)

Comment: I have posted a detailed answer to your question. Please, let me know if you have any question regarding my answer. If my answer provides relevant / helpful information regarding your question, please, upvote it. If my answer actualy answers your question, accept it too, please. To upvote, click the triangle **pointing upward above the number** (of votes) in front of the question. To accept the answer, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Answer (score 1):

**Item 1**. $D2$ **without** condition $4$ does **not** imply  $D1$.

Consider $\mu$ defined on $\mathcal{P}(\Bbb N)$ by

$ \mu(E) = \sum_{n \in E} \frac{1}{2^n} $,  if $E$ is finite, and

$ \mu(E)  = +\infty$ , if  $E$ is infinite.

It is easy to see that $\mu$ satisfies conditions $1$, $2$ and $3$  of $D2$,   but not condition $2$ of $D1$. In fact, $\Bbb N =\bigcup_{n \in \Bbb N}\{n\}$ and
$$ \mu(\Bbb N ) = +\infty \ne 2 = \sum_{n \in \Bbb N}\mu(\{n\}) $$

**Item 2.** On the other hand, $D2$ with only conditions $1$, $2$ and $4$  (no need for condition $3$) implies $D1$.

**Proof**:  Condition $1$ is the same in $D1$ and $D2$. So, it remains to be proved that conditions $1$, $2$ and $4$  of $D2$ implies condition $2$ of $D1$.

Given any countable collections $(A_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of pairwise disjoint sets of T, for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$, let $B_k = \bigcup_{n=0}^k A_n$. Then, we have that $B_{k}\subset B_{k+1} ,\forall k \in \mathbb{N}$ and
$$ \bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} B_k = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_n$$

So, using condition $4$ and $2$ of $D2$, we have

$$\mu(\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_n) = \bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} B_k= \lim_{k \to \infty} \mu(B_k) = \lim_{k \to \infty} \sum_{n=0}^k\mu(A_n)= \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\mu(A_n)$$

So, condition $2$ of $D1$ is satisfied. $\square$